# Gmail Signature does not show up

Tags: gmail, email-signature

I configured Gmail to send emails from different sender addresses. For one of these addresses, I configured a signature. This worked quite well. When creating a new email I can choose the sender address and, automatically, the signature appears in the text field.

The problem: This does not work any longer. I have no idea why. I tried this on different computers, browsers and Gmail-accounts. They all behave the same.

Any Ideas?

**Answers to questions in the comments**

- There is no special formatting in the signature. In Gmail Settings it is configured as 'only text', not as 'rich text formatted'.
- There is no "show trimmed content" (three dots) button below the message.

Comment: Do you have any special formatting in the signature? Is there a "show trimmed content" (three dots) button below the message?

Comment: I think i'm facing the same issue - checked after I saw your question. The signatures do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this problem is known to Google:

The [known issues page](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs) lists this:

> **Switching signatures doesn't work in plain text**
>
> Reported 29, October
>
> It's possible to have unique signatures in Gmail for each sending address associated with your account. Currently, switching signatures when you change the "from" address of a message only works properly in rich text mode. Click Rich formatting at the top of the compose field to change modes.

Based on this, saving the signatures as rich text should help, but I don't have this button. So I have to wait, until Google fixes this.

---

## Update: Google fixed it!

For me, it works again. It seems, that Google has fixed the problem.